# Loop for two codes and two functions in r

Tags: r

I have two codes to be done for all of my samples.

```
cr1 = MEDIPS.seqCoverage(file = "1.bam", pattern = "CG", BSgenome = BSgenome, extend = extend, shift = shift, uniq = uniq)
MEDIPS.plotSeqCoverage(seqCoverageObj=cr1, type="pie", cov.level = c(0, 5, 10, 20, 30), main="cr1")
```

Then,

```
cr2 = MEDIPS.seqCoverage(file = "2.bam", pattern = "CG", BSgenome = BSgenome, extend = extend, shift = shift, uniq = uniq)    
MEDIPS.plotSeqCoverage(seqCoverageObj=cr2, type="pie", cov.level = c(0, 5, 10, 20, 30), main="cr2")
```

I don't want to repeat the code again and again for 100 times. I tried some for loops but they are not working because " File i.bam  not found in ...". Well, I am not good at it at all. Does anyone can help me out?

So my code look like this:

```
for(i in 1:100){
  cr[i] = MEDIPS.seqCoverage(file = paste0(as.character(i),".bam"),
                             pattern = "CG", BSgenome = BSgenome, extend = extend, 
                             shift = shift, uniq = uniq)
  MEDIPS.plotSeqCoverage(seqCoverageObj=cr[i], type="pie", 
                         cov.level = c(0, 5, 10, 20, 30), main="cr",paste0(as.character(i)))
}
```

Reading bam alignment 1.bam

Total number of imported short reads: 17254741

Extending reads...

Creating GRange Object...

Keep at most one 1 read mapping to the same genomic location.

Number of remaining reads: 11148075

Loading chromosome lengths for BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19...

Get genomic sequence pattern positions...

Number of identified  CG  pattern:  26752702

Calculating sequence pattern coverage...

**Error: object 'cr' not found**

Comment: What exactly did your loops look like? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: For sample #1 I need cr1 as a vector, "1.bam" as the bam file, "cr1" as the main title of the plot. For sample #2, I will need cr2, "2.bam", "cr2" etc

Comment: @JinyongHuang ... It's so much easier if you show us the literal code you ran.  Don't just describe it.  Show us *exactly* what you tried.

Comment: Do you need all the `cr1`, `cr2`, objects after the loop? Or are you just using the for plotting and then don't need them any more. It would be easier to store them in a single list rather than 100 separate variables in your global environment if you plan to hang on to them.

Comment: @MrFlick  The answer from ThomasIsCoding has solved my problem. Thank you anyway.

Comment: OK, but it may have also just created a new problem if you need to keep using those values multiple times. Generally you want to gather related values in lists and avoid `get/assign` to make it easier to do things in an R-like way.

Comment: @MrFlick Each time I asked a question, I learned more than how to solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the thing you are looking after, but you can still have a try, where the number similar actions is assumed as 100, i.e.,

```
list2env(setNames(lapply(paste0(seq(100),".bam"),
                         function(v) MEDIPS.seqCoverage(file = v, pattern = "CG", BSgenome = BSgenome, extend = extend, shift = shift, uniq = uniq)),
                  paste0("cr",seq(100))),
         envir = .GlobalEnv)

sapply(paste0("cr",seq(100)),function(v) MEDIPS.plotSeqCoverage(seqCoverageObj=get(v), type="pie", cov.level = c(0, 5, 10, 20, 30), main=v))
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked as exactly what I want. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JinyongHuang Great! If you think my answer is helpful, please consider upvote/accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your working directory is set correctly. The " File i.bam not found in ..." means that file is not in the same directory you are currently in.

```
getwd()
```

will show you what directory you are currently in. If the file is in downloads, you can use

```
setwd()
```

to change your directory to downloads to access the file.

**Update from comment**

```
for(i in 1:100){
cr[i] = MEDIPS.seqCoverage(file = cat(paste0(as.character(i),".bam")),
pattern = "CG", BSgenome = BSgenome, extend = extend, 
shift = shift, uniq = uniq)

MEDIPS.plotSeqCoverage(seqCoverageObj=cr[i], type="pie", 
cov.level = c(0, 5, 10, 20, 30), main=cr[i])
}
```

Comment: I have set the working directory correctly. There must be something wrong on my code that it can't find my files.

Comment: Gotcha, I think I misread it initially. In your for loop, try this:
`file = cat(paste0(as.character(i), ".bam")`.

Comment: You don't want `cat()` in there. `cat()` will return NULL. The `paste0()` should be good enough for building strings.

Comment: Error in MEDIPS.seqCoverage(file = cat(paste0(as.character(i), ".bam")),  : 
  Must specify a bam or txt file.

Comment: Error in MEDIPS.plotSeqCoverage(seqCoverageObj = cr[i], type = "pie",  : 
  object 'cr' not found

Comment: So I guess main = cr[i] is not correct. Should be something like main ="cr[i]"